# What do you call someone who

Tags: word-choice, epithet-requests

What would you call a person who gains a sense of godlikeness, but uses their knowledge and omnipotence for what they feel is the good of others? I ask because I'm wondering what to call myself. I have decided to pursue psychiatry to have power over others but only to make them and their lives better; it is that feeling of making someone infinitely better that I crave so what am I???

Comment: Someone with [delusions of grandeur. . .](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delusions+of+grandeur) I mean you're calling yourself "god-like".

Comment: You have the God complex, something you will learn about in psych and hopefully overcome. Also check bodhisattva.

Comment: I'd call that person *Someone who shouldn't become a psychiatrist.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that's hilariously apropos.

Comment: If you do opt to use the expression *bodhisattva* but your future patients  are unfamiliar with buddhism, you might have to explain the concept. I for one, have never heard this term.

Answer (score 3):

You are a **bodhisattva**. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva) about the concept:

> In Buddhism, a bodhisattva (Sanskrit: बोधिसत्त्व bodhisattva; Pali: बोधिसत्त bodhisatta) is an enlightened (bodhi) being (sattva). Traditionally, a bodhisattva is anyone who, motivated by great compassion, has generated bodhicitta, which is a spontaneous wish to attain Buddhahood for the benefit of all sentient beings.

From the Wikipedia article on [Buddhahood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhahood):

> The bodhisattva attains liberation and wishes to benefit as many beings as possible. A bodhisattva who has accomplished this goal is called a samyaksambuddha. A samyaksambuddha can establish the Dharma and lead disciples to enlightenment.

The term has very specific religious meanings, but it is fairly broadly known nowadays as someone who has decided to direct their enlightenment to benefit the world, rather than dissolving in nirvana, i.e. removing oneself from the world.  I would say it is popularly understood as a concept rather than a religious doctrine.

However, I would not go around just calling myself a bodhisattva without irony or at least comparative qualification like "I think my personal drive is what is described in Buddhism by the concept of Bodhisattva."

Comment: Why not include the link and a summary? Yes, I can Google it, but why should I? EL&U is about providing "answers" not suggested links.

Comment: My apologies. I am new. I thought those posing questions are responsible for their own basic research.

Comment: Thanks you all for answers. I feel like the bodhisattva one real describes me. I sorry If I worded me question badly and I did try my own research but I felt the God complex and megalomania were much more sinister than my intention to have the power and yes technically use it for my own happiness but the fact that the happiness I seek contradicts the power  hungriness confused the Google

Comment: You already have the great advantage of being highly self-reflective and honest with yourself. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks you very much for your blessings and best of luck in your life as well

Comment: In my opinion, this doesn't really fit the OPs intention. He isn't forgoing helping himself by helping others. He's essentially just trying to use his powers for good instead of evil.

Comment: @Mike OP confirmed in comments that it does fit. Also, bodhisattva is not self-sacrificial. She is bound by certain commitments, which would make helping herself a good thing, since she is dedicated to helping others. As long as this is what would be happening, there should not be a negative intention or consequence.

Comment: Bodhisattva refers to forgoing nirvana to bring others to enlightenment. Also, the OP has learned ESL. For this reason they seem to have missed the intricacies of the word you suggested. I think s/he is just happy it's a word with a positive essence, as opposed to the words s/he discovered while googling.

Comment: True. It appears that OP has some trepidation about the awesome powers of psychiatry, characterizing them as godlike. It doesn't necessarily mean s/he has a god complex. And it doesn't mean that s/he should be discouraged from trying to help others.

Comment: The formatting of your answer made it look quite jumbled, and it was difficult to tell what was and wasn't a quote. I've taken the liberty of adding blockquotes and putting the links in more reader-friendly places.